# How do I validate multiple radio buttons in a ASP.NET repeater in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, repeater

I have multiple radio buttons and I'm using a GroupName to choose at
 least 1 of the 2 options. I can't seem to get the GroupName so I can
 validate to make sure 1 of 2 has been selected with a submit button is >clicked.

```
 <myRepeater>

     <asp:CustomValidator 
       ID="CustomValidator1" 
       runat="server" 
       ErrorMessage="* Select an option" 
       ForeColor="#ff0000" 
       OnServerValidate="option1_Validation" 
       Display="Dynamic" /> 

     <asp:RadioButton 
       ID="rdOption1" 
       Text="Option_1" 
       GroupName="gnOption1" 
       runat="server" />

     <asp:RadioButton 
       ID="rdOption2" 
       Text="Option_2" 
       GroupName="gnOption1" 
       runat="server" />

 </myRepeater>
```

Code:

```
 protected void option1_Validation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
 {
     bool itemSelected = false;
     foreach (RepeaterItem ri in myRepeater.Items)
     {
         RadioButton rb= (RadioButton)ri.FindControl("gnOption1");
         {               
             if (rb.GroupName == "gnOption1" && rb.Checked == true)
             {
                  itemSelected = true; 
             }
             args.IsValid = itemSelected;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  What happens when you run this?

Comment: I'm not sure how this even works. It looks like all of the radio buttons within the repeater have the same group name, and so the user would only be able to select one radio button out of all of them.

Comment: I don't get an error. It just doesn't validate at all. I have 3 sets of 2 radio buttons. Each set has a different GroupName ex: gnOption1, gnOption2, gnOption3. Before I put the radio buttons inside the repeater it works fine when trying to validate them by the GroupName , but inside the repeater I can't find the GroupName

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to cast the sender object as a Custom Validator:

`CustomValidator myCustomValidator = (CustomValidator)sender;`

Then find the parent of the CustomValidator, in this case the Repeater Item:

`RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)myCustomValidator.Parent;`

And finally get the control:

`RadioButton rb= (RadioButton)ri.FindControl("gnOption1");`

You'll have to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thats my code above. sorry about the format I don't know how to fix it. But the code displays a error even when 1 of my radio buttons are selected

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void game1_Validation(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        CustomValidator CustomValidator1 = (CustomValidator)sender;
        bool itemSelected = false;
        RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)CustomValidator1.Parent;         
        {
            if (ri is RadioButton)
            {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)ri.FindControl("gnOption11");
                if (rb.GroupName == "gnOption1" && rb.Checked == true)
                {
                    itemSelected = true;
                }
            }
        }
        args.IsValid = itemSelected;
    }
```

Comment: The deal is you're trying to find the controls by `GroupName`, so on the `FindControl` method you should pass the `ControlID`, that's why is throwing the `System.NullReferenceException: rb was null`.